# Example 5.13 in Bonsall and Duncan Complete Normed Algebras

Tags: spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Example 5.13 goes like this.

Let $A=C(\Gamma)$, where $\Gamma=\{z: |z|=1\}$, let $B$ be the image of the disc algebra $A(\Delta)$ under the isometric isomorphism $f\rightarrow f\restriction_\Gamma$ and $u(z)=z$. Then $Sp(A,u)=\Gamma, Sp(B,u)=\Delta.$

Can any one tell me why $Sp(B,u)=\Delta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is a commutative, unital Banach algebra, and $a\in A$, then $\mathrm{Sp}(A,a)=\hat a(M_A)$, where $\hat a$ denotes the Gelfand transform of $a$ and $M_A$ denotes the maximal ideal space (or character space) of $A$.

The maximal ideal space of the disk algebra $B$ (following your notation) can be identified with the closed unit disk, and so $\mathrm{Sp}(B,u)=\hat u(M_A)$. But the Gelfand transform of $u$ is just the function $z\mapsto z$ on the defined on the closed unit disk, thus the spectrum is $\Delta$.

Comment: Thank you. But they say that $B$ is the IMAGE of the disc algebra under the isometric isomorphism. So I am confused. Is the spectrum considered in the disc Algebra or the image of the map?

Comment: Isometric isomorphism preserves the maximal ideal space. The disk algebra does not change, it is simply represented on a smaller compact space. The character space of the algebra generated by polynomials is always the "polynomial convex hull" of the set, which is the union of the set and the bounded components of the complement.

Comment: OK thank you very much.